# BASH: Parsing CSV into array using IFS last array element missing when is an empty string

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

When I try to read a file and parse CSV into an array using IFS, the array is missing the last element if the last element has no value. I want to sanitize by using the value of `${#array[@]}` to ensure the CSV has the correct number of columns but for rows with a null last column the behavior is incorrect.

What am I missing?

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do

  oldifs=$IFS
  IFS=','
  array=($line)
  IFS=$oldifs
  echo "${array[@]} : num_elements =${#array[@]}"

done < $1
```

list.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh list.csv
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : num_elements =9
1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : num_elements =9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 : num_elements =8
```